Help me clarify the cardinality for some concepts for a model
So I have a security model and am having problem with deciding the cardinality. This is what I have now:

Threat may result in Attack.

Direct Association
One-to-Many (0..*)


Attack exploits Vulnerability.

Direct Association
Many(1..*)-to-One



About the classes:

Vulnerability refers to 'Software Bug', etc.

Attack refers to 'Malware', etc.

Threat can be 'Environmental', 'Internal', 'External'.


Are theses cardinalities appropriate for the meaning I described above?
Image:


I think we still need more information. What I'm struggling with is visualizing the proposed structure. Which of these entities can exist independently of the others? Which entities require the existence of other entities. This all derives from the requirements you've been given.

@GregBurghardt I understood ahahah
I think I am starting to understand what you are saying. I created the model, does the image of the model help?

@Alexa the question now is clear enough. I just narrowed down your final question, since "best" without definition tends to attract opinion based answers.

As an exercise, this seems reasonable for the most part. In principle, many different attacks could exploit the same set of vulnerabilities, so I'd model that as many-to-many (1..* - 1..*). In the real world, there is no one correct/canonical way to do it - it all depends on what the application is about. If it's made for an existing business or an organization, it depends on how they think about the stuff they are going to use this application for. On top of that, it's possible for different developers to model the same thing differently, and end up with roughly the same functionality.

For example on how the context matters, take Christophe's suggestion that there may be known, but yet unexploited vulnerabilities. In an application that tracks known vulnerabilities, you'd make multiplicity be 0..*. In an application that exclusively tracks historical instances of attacks, you might make it 1..*. If this is a homework assignment, I'd be more focused on being able to present the examiner with a reasonable justification/reasoning for your final design (in fact, you could include it as a short explanatory text together with your diagram).

I would strongly recommend to not only consider software issues as "vulnerabilities", but also physical security, processes, human factors etc. Many attacks involve some form of social engineering.

Thanks everyone, all your comments helped me see different perspectives I didn't consider before!

This model is interesting and is a very good base.
I spotted only one potential issue: The diagrams tells that a Vulnerability is exploited by many Attack:

It is probably true but it's not what you said in the narrative. (I suspect the multiplicity is simply on the wrong side).
The diagram leaves unspecified how many vulnerabilities an attack could exploit
Also in real life, vulnerabilities may exist that are not yet exploited, so on the current side of the multiplicity, it should be 0..* (or simply *, according to official UML shortcuts).

Some additional suggestions:

Do you have the case that attacks are identified and registered while the vulnerabilities that it exploits are not yet known? (hint: think twice when considering a minimum of 1)

You may want to complete the information on the association between threat and attacks, by specifying the multiplicity also in the opposite direction (i.e. how many different threats could result in the same attack. This is not essential, considering that you used only associations that are specified to be navigable only in one direction. But it could help to make the right design decisions.

you could be interested in an advanced UML feature, by specifying +/exist_because_of. The / tells that this association is derived and not independent.


My only concern with the domain model is that security risks and threats might also be unrelated to vulnerabilities (e. g. human factors, organisational issues, bad practices of actors using the systems, etc). But maybe these are excluded from the scope of your model. Anyway, if needed, you could easily cover this with minor adaptations to the multiplicities.
Remark: in UML-speak the term is "multiplicity". UML uses "cardinality" as one instance of a multiplicity.

Thank you for the help, you gave me a lot to consider and I managed to complete my model!

@Alexa thank you for your feedback which is very motivating

Let me tell you how I would usually use these terms. That should help you to derive the cardinalities (or multiplicities) by yourself:

Attack

is something a malware does at one point in time.

The malware itself is a tool used for an attack, not the attack itself. An attack may try to exploit different vulnerabilities in a system, and each vulnerability may be exploited by different attacks. So it should be an m:n relationship, and an attack will usually exploit at least one vulnerability.

there can be contexts where it makes sense to record attacks without a vulnerability (for example, when the vulnerabilty isn't known at the time of the attack)

alternatively, an Attack object might not refer to different attacks at different points in time, but refer to the same type of attack (i.e. same malware trying to exploit the same set of vulnerabilities). Still it will be an n:m relationship to Vulnerability.



Vulnerability

can be a bug, or maybe an intentionally placed backdoor in the system
even when it is known, it is not guaranteed it will be ever exploited by an attack


Threat and Security risks

are terms which are often used synonymously. Each security risk is a threat to your system, and each threat also a security risk. Threats / security risks may exist because of vulnerabilities in some software, but that's not the only possible reason, there may exist because of organizational failures (like people writing down their passwords on post-its under their desk). Still, you have to decide if your system should manage such kind of non-technical threats, or not.
alternatively, the term "security risk" might be used as some attribute of a threat. For example, if Security Risk has only the values "low", "medium" and "high", it would be simply an attribute of a threat. "Security risk" might also be used to quantify the probability of a threat to be exploited.



It makes also a difference if you want your model to describe the security properties of a single, specific system, or if it should be a system-agnostic model. Vulnerabilities of a specific system may refer to some kind of specific bug, vulnerabilities in general can only be classified to certain types (like "stack overflow error", "forgotten backdoor" etc).
In the end, there is not just "one" right answer to your question - context matters. As others have written in the comments, the right semantic depends on the goals and use cases for this model.

Thank you for this interesting answer. However I am not completely sure that security experts will agree  with all definitions. In particular, the attacker is in general the actor  operating malware to achieve some purpose (extorsion, stealing information, destabilization, etc). The malware is only the tool used to perform the attack. We can all agree that the attack can refer to one specific malicious operation or a familiy of likewise operations. But there is a big difference between a threat (possibity of an attack) and a risk which also looks at probability of threat, potential damages etc

@Christophe: thanks for the feedback, I tried to address your points.

much less controversial. The questiin if of course if a risk is assessed for a single threat or severals - see also here: https://informationsecurity.wustl.edu/vulnerabilities-threats-and-risks-explained/

@Christophe: thanks for the link. AFAIK, the term "Security risk" has a colloquial meaning (where it is used a synom for threat) as well as a more formal meaning, as it is defined in that article. The OP will have to make the decision which one they prefer for their Domain model.

I agree ! There are a lot of possible meanings, and a focus on the scope, i.e. choice is required. Btw I already upvoted your answer as it complements with domain information my own answer which is more focused on modeling aspects.

@DocBrown Thank you! The information you gave really helped me decide!
